# Appium reset session on cucumber hook

Tags: ruby, cucumber, appium

Is it possible to create a hook on cucumber that when it reaches a scenario with a specific tag, it will reset the session of the appium server with new capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible:

```
def new_driver
   Appium::Driver.new(caps: caps).start_driver
end

Before('@reset') do
   new_driver
end
```

where `caps` is a hash of desired capabilities.